# Java/Swing: Create text fields upon clicking a rectangle

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an app where the user can upload an image, draw rectangles on top of the image using the mouse for annotation, and each rectangle upon click will display an empty text field on the right as shown in pic for the user to attach comments to that certain region. [image] Right now the program will upload the image and lets the user draw rectangles on top of it (the left side of the image shown above is implemented), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the program create and display an empty text field when the user clicks on a rectangle for the first time (implementing the right side of the image shown). The rectangle will also be highlighted in red when selected, and if a comment is already there, the comment should be in the text box upon click. My guess is I will have to create the JTextFields in the DrawingArea class and somehow pass it over to the ImageAnnotator class? or I have to import the ImageAnnotator inside the DrawingArea and input the TextFields there directly? Or maybe there is a connection that I'm not making. I'm also having trouble displaying the image name on the screen, even though I'm passing it to the JLabel. Any help is appreciated.

DrawingArea.java:

```
public class DrawingArea extends JPanel
    {
        private final static int AREA_SIZE = 490;
        private BufferedImage image =
            new BufferedImage(AREA_SIZE, AREA_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        private Rectangle shape;
        private ArrayList<Box> rectangles = new ArrayList<Box>();
        public String imageName = ""; // this will store the image/file name

        public DrawingArea()
        {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
            addMouseListener(ml);
            addMouseMotionListener(ml);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            //  Custom code to support painting from the BufferedImage

            if (image != null)
            {
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
            
            Color foreground = g.getColor();


            for (Box b : rectangles)
            {
                g.setColor( b.getForeground() );
                Rectangle r = b.getRectangle();
                g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            }

            //  Paint the Rectangle as the mouse is being dragged

            if (shape != null)
            {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2d.draw( shape );
            }
        }

        public void addRectangle(Rectangle rectangle, Color color)
        {
            //  Draw the Rectangle onto the BufferedImage

            Box b = new Box(color, rectangle);
            rectangles.add( b );
            repaint();
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            rectangles.clear();
            repaint();
        }
        
        public void loadImage() {
            ...
            this.imageName = f.getName(); //this is where I pass the file name
            ...
        }
        
        public static BufferedImage scaleImage(int w, int h, BufferedImage img) throws Exception {...}

        class MyMouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter
        {
            private Point startPoint;

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                startPoint = e.getPoint();
                shape = new Rectangle();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
            {
                int x = Math.min(startPoint.x, e.getX());
                int y = Math.min(startPoint.y, e.getY());
                int width = Math.abs(startPoint.x - e.getX());
                int height = Math.abs(startPoint.y - e.getY());

                shape.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (shape.width != 0 || shape.height != 0)
                {
                    addRectangle(shape, e.getComponent().getForeground());
                }

                shape = null;
            }
        }       
    }
```

ImageAnnotator.java:

```
public class ImageAnnotator extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    Model model;
    private JLabel ImageName;
    DrawingArea drawingArea;
    ButtonPanel buttonPanel;
    GroupLayout gl_contentPane;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ImageAnnotator(Model m) {
        super();
        this.model = m;
        setTitle("Image Annotator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 850, 646);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        drawingArea = new DrawingArea();
        
        ImageName = new JLabel(drawingArea.imageName); // here I'm trying to set the filename
        buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel( drawingArea );
        
        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Comments");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 17));
        
        gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(drawingArea, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 490, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 128, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                    .addGap(117))
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(121)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(buttonPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ImageName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 254, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(451, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(drawingArea, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 490, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(ImageName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(buttonPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        contentPane.add(drawingArea);
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }
```

Box.java:

```
public class Box {
    int bWidth, bHeight, bX, bY;
    String bImageName, bComment;
    
    Color foreground;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    
    public Box(int width, int height) {
        bWidth = width;
        bHeight = height;
    }
    
    public Box(Color foreground, Rectangle rectangle) {
        this.foreground = foreground;
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }
    
    public void setImageName(String imageName) { bImageName = imageName; }
    public String getImageName() { return bImageName; }
    
    public void setComment(String comment) { bComment = comment; }
    public String getComment() { return bComment; }
    
    public void setX(int x) { bX = x; }
    public int getX() { return bX; }
    
    public void setY(int y) { bY = y; }
    public int getY() { return bY; }
    
    public Color getForeground()
    {
        return foreground;
    }

    public void setForeground(Color foreground)
    {
        this.foreground = foreground;
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle()
    {
        return rectangle;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *I'm also having trouble displaying the image name on the screen, even though I'm passing it to the JLabel.* - why do you keep deleting your old questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64080866/131872. I already suggested when the problem was.

Comment: @camickr i'm sorry, it's just cause I solved the previous problems I was having. I didn't want people to read the question which was already solved.

Comment: The logic needs to be in the DrawingPanel class. I would use a double click to indicate you want to display a JTextArea. Then you iterate through the ArrayList to see if any rectangle "contains" the mouse point. If so, then you create and add the text field to the panel. The panel will need to use a null layout. As the text is entered, I would then save it as a property of the rectangle class. So the next time you double click you display the text in the text area to allow it to be changed.

Comment: My main point was you were already given a suggestion on why the label has no value. So I'm not sure why the question was asked again, or why you didn't ask a specific question if you didn't understand the suggestion/solution. Also, when you delete a question we can no longer see it, so why should I continue to help when it appears you ignore the suggestions.

Comment: *"didn't want people to read the question which was already solved."* SO is meant as a repository of answers to solved questions. Those answers are for everyone - now or searching later. **Do *not* delete solved questions.** Instead write an answer or choose an existing answer, and tick it as accepted.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry about that, there were no answers to my previous questions, so I couldn't tick anything as accepted to close the question. But now I know I can answer my own question and close it.

Comment: @camickr I'm gonna try your suggestion for the JLabel, sorry I didn't see it before. But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Generally, you construct the whole GUI before the user does anything.  You have a drawing JPanel on the left and a comment JPanel on the right.  Both can be constructed before shown to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you probably need is some kind of listener or observer that can be used to notify interested parties when the `Box` is selected

```
public interface BoxSelectionListener extends EventListener {
    public void didSelect(Box box);
}
```

This would be implemented by the parent part of the UI that is managing both the drawing and input components, when triggered, the interested party would then take appropriate action based on its needs.

Next, we need to add some management code for the `DrawingArea` to manage the listener support.  This is made easier as Swing components have some handy support

```
public void addBoxSelectionListener(BoxSelectionListener listener) {
    listenerList.add(BoxSelectionListener.class, listener);
}

public void removeBoxSelectionListener(BoxSelectionListener listener) {
    listenerList.remove(BoxSelectionListener.class, listener);
}

protected void fireBoxSelected(Box box) {
    BoxSelectionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(BoxSelectionListener.class);
    // Normally, I'd create a event object, which would wrap the source (this) and
    // the Box together, but if there are no listeners, it's a bit of
    // a waste to do so, so I return early in those cases
    if (listeners.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (BoxSelectionListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.didSelect(box);
    }
}
```

Okay, pretty simple, you can add or remove a listener and trigger the event to fire when you need to.

Okay, now the "slightly" harder bit.  When the mouse is pressed and released, you need to make some decisions about what to do, do you want to select a box or do you want to draw a new one.

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

    private Point startPoint;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // Mark the clip point
        startPoint = e.getPoint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // Only create the shape when dragging starts
        if (shape == null) {
            shape = new Rectangle();
        }
        int x = Math.min(startPoint.x, e.getX());
        int y = Math.min(startPoint.y, e.getY());
        int width = Math.abs(startPoint.x - e.getX());
        int height = Math.abs(startPoint.y - e.getY());

        shape.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (shape != null) {
            if (shape.width != 0 || shape.height != 0) {
                addRectangle(shape, e.getComponent().getForeground());
            }
        } else {
            for (Box b : rectangles) {
                if (b.getRectangle().contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    didSelect(b);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        startPoint = null;
        shape = null;
    }
}
```

So, some modifications to your code.

1. Until the drag is detected, we don't create a new `shape`, this allows us some wiggle room in our decision making process.
2. If the user "clicked" the component, we scan through the available shapes and determine if the user clicked one, if one was clicked we call `didSelect`

Why do we do this?  The main reason for doing this is it allows use to detect when some one is creating overlapping rectangles (more or less), but with any luck they won't do that, because it makes selections super difficult.

The `didSelect` method is a simple opportunity to handle all the things you need to do when you want to "select" a particular box.  This decouples the functionality and allow you to make decisions about when it might be called

```
public void didSelect(Box box) {
    // Probably assign this to a "assigned" or "selected" property
    // so it can painted differently
    // And now we want to notify some kind of listener so that
    // it can update the UI as required
    
    fireBoxSelected(box);
}
```

Comment: I added the code for the ```addBoxSelectionListener()``` and ```removeBoxSelectionListener()``` in the DrawingArea class and it's giving me the error  ```The method add(Class<T>, T) in the type EventListenerList is not applicable for the arguments (Class<BoxSelectionListener>, BoxSelectionListener)``` , and I'm also getting the same error for the other function. Also in the ```fireProtectedBox()``` function, I'm getting the error ```The method getListeners(Class<T>) in the type EventListenerList is not applicable for the arguments (Class<BoxSelectionListener>)```.

Comment: .. Of course, search the site first. It's likely this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @RedApple Sorry, my bad, `BoxSelectionListener` should also extend from `EventListener`

Answer (score 0):

You could go with when you click on a square, you could either, capture the mouse's location and do some math and build a `jpanel` with an invisible `jtextbox`, or do the same thing but spawn the panel when they draw the box.